# httpd: Syntax error on line 1011 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: GracefulShutDownTimeout> directive missing closing '>'

Tags: apache, localhost, hosting, web-hosting

I am New to web hosting, i am creating virtual hosts, i want to create new site on my VPS (Hostgator with no cpanel). I edited httpd.conf file as instructed and my edits are as follows..

Previously

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier 
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
```

My Edits..

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier 
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@glinks.ga
    DocumentRoot /var/www/glinks.ga/public_html
    ServerName www.glilnks.ga
    ErrorLog/var/www/glinks.ga/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/glinks.ga/requests.log
</VirtualHost>GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
```

but i am getting error

```
    New files of configuration for Apache web server
     were not built due to errors in configuration templates: 
    httpd: Syntax error on line 1011 
of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: GracefulShutDownTimeout> directive missing closing '>' .
```

How do i solve..

Comment: What is the 1011th line ? Is it the line with the extra GracefulShutDownTimeout (`</VirtualHost>GracefulShutDownTimeout 3`) ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the line `</VirtualHost>GracefulShutDownTimeout 3` : add a line return between the two directives:

```
</VirtualHost>
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
```

You should also fix the logs directives in your virtual host ([ErrorLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog) was missing a space, [CustomLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) was missing the format):

```
ErrorLog /var/www/glinks.ga/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/glinks.ga/requests.log common
```